# How to configure lampp to use pecl_http

Tags: php, xampp, php-extension, pecl, lampp

*(running lampp on ubuntu 12.10)*

Hi,

I am trying to use the HttpRequest class of pecl_http

my php script is as follows

```
<?php

        $r = new HttpRequest('http://localhost/test?msg=hello', HttpRequest::METH_GET);
        $r->setOptions(array('lastmodified' => filetime('local.rss')));
        $r->addQueryData(array('category' => 3));
        try{
            $r->send();
            if($r->getResponseCode() == 200){
                file_put_contents('local.rss', $r->getResponseBody());
            }
        }
        catch (HttpException $ex){
            echo $ex;
        }
?>
```

I have installed pecl_http by doing the following
sudo /opt/lampp/bin/pecl install pecl_http

and when running `phpinfo()` I get the extensions dir to be `/opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226` and an `ls` of that folder shows:

```
aly@krypton:/opt/lampp$ ls -al /opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226
total 3208
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root    4096 Jan  2 17:58 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root    4096 Jan  2 16:35 ..
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 2333400 Jan  2 17:58 http.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  156824 Nov 17 14:33 oci8.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  144232 Nov 17 14:33 opcache.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  132480 Nov 17 14:33 pgsql.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   72488 Jan  2 17:56 propro.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   42960 Nov 17 14:33 radius.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  109746 Jan  2 17:57 raphf.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   61733 Jan  2 17:55 uploadprogress.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  203784 Nov 17 14:33 xdebug.so
```

I have also edited the `php.ini` located at `/opt/lampp/etc/php.ini` to have the following lines:

```
include_path = ".:/php/includes:/opt/lampp/include/php"
extension=propro.so
extension=raphf.so
extension=http.so
```

But when I load the php I still get the error `Class 'HttpRequest' not found`

Any ideas?